# save div with form elements in html without canvas or with canvas?

Tags: jquery, html

i have tried to capture div with canvas,its working fine, but it doesn't save the form element,
i have image just like Comic - speech bubble ,and i have positioned textarea in it, where user types his/her text , when user hits the Save Button, it should save the Comic-speech bubble along with text inserted in it as **IMAGE**. so can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: You're going to need some web framework to generate an image on the server side such as an ASP.NET or PHP web server application. I don't know of anything in jquery/html5 that would transform your inputs into an image on the client side.

Comment: *"i have tried to capture div with canvas,its working fine, but it doesn't save the form element..."* Why not just get the text from the form element and render it to the canvas?